# Print different lines based on what radio button is checked Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to print different text based on what radio button is checked. How should my if statement look, so that I can see what button is checked?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title("Cost Analysis")                         

RadioPlanned=Radiobutton(predictionframe1, text="option 1", value=1)
RadioPlanned.grid(row=0,column=0)

RadioReal=Radiobutton(predictionframe1, text="option 2", value=2)
RadioReal.grid(row=1,column=0)

def printing():

    if # radio button "option 1 " is checked
        print("option 1")

    elif # radio button "option 2 " is checked
        print("option 2")

but=Button(myApp, text="button", command=printing)
but.grid(row=2, column=0)

myApp.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, here, this is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import ttk

myApp = Tk()
myApp.title("Cost Analysis")                         

option=IntVar()

RadioPlanned=Radiobutton(myApp, text="option 1", value=1, variable=option)
RadioPlanned.grid(row=0,column=0)

RadioReal=Radiobutton(myApp, text="option 2", value=2, variable=option)
RadioReal.grid(row=1,column=0)

def printing():

    if option.get()==1:
        print("option 1")
    elif option.get()==2:
        print("option 2")

but=Button(myApp, text="button", command=printing)
but.grid(row=2, column=0)

myApp.mainloop()
```